# Only execute Before Update trigger if conditions are met

Tags: apex, trigger, update

I have a trigger on the opportunity object with the below format:

Before Update on Opportunity

- Create List of ID's
- Create Set Using SOQL Query
- Create Map Using SOQL Query

Iterate over Opportunities in Trigger
If conditions are met - do something
If some other conditions are met - do something else

- Update List

This works fine, however every time a user edits an opportunity, 2 SOQL queries are going to be run. Is there a way to only execute the trigger if a condition is met (in this case, a checkbox on the opp == true)?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Is that checkbox field also an opportunity field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add this sort of guard in your trigger:

```
Set<Id> ids = new Set<Id>();
for (Opportunity opp : Trigger.new) {
    if (opp.Checkbox__c) {
        Opportunity old = Trigger.oldMap.get(opp.Id);
        if (opp.Checkbox__c != old.Checkbox__c) {
            ids.add(opp.Id);
        }
    }
}
if (ids.size() > 0) {
    // Query
}
```

so that the queries are only done if the checkbox is checked and when the checkbox value has changed (if that is appropriate too).

Comment: Shouldn't you be referencing trigger.oldMap for old ?

Comment: I should have just edited....always forget I can do that, sorry

Comment: Hi guys, thanks so much for the help here. Using some kind of If Statement was my first thought, but then I figured I'd just be putting my SOQL statements in the loop of triggers so I decided against it. I hadn't considered using a set before and then updating after. This works great. Thanks again for the help, much appreciated.